# Como fixa colunas de um ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listview

Tenho o seguinte *ListView* abaixo, preciso deixa as 3 primeiras colunas fixas e permitir que o restante role com scroll.

```
<td colspan="4">
  <div class="GradeDados" style="position: relative; width: 1000px; height: 400px;
    z-index: 1; overflow: scroll;">
    <asp:ListView ID="livCamposForm" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="livCamposForm_OnItemDataBound"
      DataKeyNames="IdCampoFormulario">
      <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblCodigo" runat="server">Código</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblClasificacao" runat="server">Clasificação</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblDescricao" runat="server">Descrição</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblJaneiro" runat="server">Janeiro</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblFevereiro" runat="server">Fevereiro</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblMarco" runat="server">Março</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblAbril" runat="server">Abril</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblMaio" runat="server">Maio</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblJunho" runat="server">Junho</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblJulho" runat="server">Julho</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblAgosto" runat="server">Agosto</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblSetembro" runat="server">Setembro</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblOutubro" runat="server">Outubro</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblNovembro" runat="server">Novembro</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblDezembro" runat="server">Dezembro</asp:Label>
            </th>
            <th>
              <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server">Total</asp:Label>
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr id="itemplaceholder" runat="server">
          </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="<%#setClass(Container.DataItem)%>">
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCodigoEdit" class="<%#setClass(Container.DataItem)%>" runat="server"
              Text='<%# Eval("Codigo")%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblClasificacaoEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Clasificacao")%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDescricaoEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Descricao")%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuJaneiro" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Janeiro"))%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuFevereiro" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Fevereiro"))%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuMarco" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Marco"))%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuAbril" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Abril"))%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuMaio" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Maio"))%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuJunho" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Junho"))%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuJulho" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Julho"))%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuAgosto" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Agosto"))%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuSetembro" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Setembro"))%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuOutubro" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Outubro"))%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuNovembro" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Novembro"))%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuDezembro" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Dezembro"))%>' />
          </td>
          <td>
            <uc7:NumericEdit ID="NuTotal" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Text='<%# DecimalPontoVigula(Eval("Total"))%>' />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
  </div>
</td>
```

[image: form]

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: pesquisei sobre o assunto o que encontrei foi o uso do evento "ColumnWidthChanging ":  e.NewWidth = listView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;.... mas no ListView não tem a propriedade  "Columns"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sendo uma [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx), você pode definir a propriedade `Frozen` como `true`:

```
this.livCamposForm.Columns["lblCodigo"].Frozen = true;
```

Com [`ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) creio não ser possível fazer isto. A definição de colunas é bem diferente e o objeto não é especializado.

Comment: Entendi, até consegui com o GridView, mas preciso que os campos recebam valores e esse efeito só conheço com a utilização do ListView.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza como assim `preciso que os campos recebam valores e esse efeito só conheço com a utilização do ListView`? Dizes, cada campo receber um valor em determinado momento?

Comment: @jbueno, veja a imagem, na quinta linha  da coluna "Janeiro"  o usuário tem a opção de digita um valor decimal, após isso uso o valor para fazer alguns cálculos e salva no banco. Quando o usuário começa a rola a grade até dezembro a descrição some e isso dificulta o entendimento de quem for preencher o form.